# For loop over multiline strings in bash without iterating over each line

Tags: bash

Take the following example script:

```sh
foo="multi
line"
bar="multi
line"
for X in $foo $bar
do
    echo $X
    echo "break"
done
```

The output will be:

```
multi
break
line
break
...
```

How can I iterate over the entire variable, not each line? The desired output would be:

```
multi
line
break
multi
line
break
```

Apologies as I'm sure this must be a duplicate, but it's impossible to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)

```
$ cat ip.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo="multi
line"
bar="multi
line"
for X in "$foo" "$bar"
do
    echo "$X"
    echo "break"
done

$ ./ip.sh 
multi
line
break
multi
line
break
```